# How to say "I want to see A doing this"?

Tags: grammar, nominalization

I want to say **"I want to see A doing this"** to my Japanese friend,

I know that

> これ = This
>
> やっている = doing
>
> 見たい = want to see

but I'm not sure how should I put them together?

I tried researching online and came up with

> Aさんがやっているを見たい。

but I don't think it is correct...

**Edit**
YES the suggested question has a clear answer. Nevertheless, if you are looking for a way to construct such sentences, you would not really search "How to use の?" since it would imply that you know the nominaliser is required in the first place?
In this case, I think the question that should be considered duplicate should be like "How to use の in the sentence?"

Comment: Use the nominalizer の: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/9831 ・　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11566/9831 ・ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29926/9831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the nominalizers こと and の?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/what-is-the-difference-between-the-nominalizers-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-and-%e3%81%ae)

Answer (score 3):

You can say "Aさんがこれをやっているのを見たい"

I want to see A = Aさんを見たい 
doing this = これをやっている 
A doing this = Aさんがこれをやっている

Comment: なぜそこに nominalizer の「の」が必要なのかを説明していただかないと、学習者にはわかりません・・・

Comment: @moderators こんな編集approveしていいんですか？https://japanese.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14786　 Edit の際は original author's intent を尊重しないといけないはずですよね？ Review する際も reject の理由の一つとして「This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.」という文言が出てくるはずです。「ところ」も追加されて、明らかにoriginal author の意図を超えます。

Comment: Apparently it's been accepted by two other users. The edit page says "We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary." The original answerer has left the site, and ところ should be correct to any Japanese natives.

Comment: "We welcome~~ necessary" ←そこしか読まはらへんかったんですね・・もっとあったはずですが・・How to edit ... fix grammatical or spelling errors とか clarify meaning without changing it とか correct minor mistakes とか・・へえ、サイトを去った人の場合は "original author's intent は尊重しなくてええんですか。。やめた人のポストは好きに変えてかまわんってんですね。。。

Comment: What original poster said is all intact.

Comment: The important thing for us is not who wins but what is the correct information. That is not always easy to achieve, but can be possible by collaboration, in friendly atmosphere, but not through any manipulation.

Comment: @karlalou You're welcome to post additional information like this, but I think in this case it might be best to do so as a separate answer instead of an edit.

Comment: @snailplane What I think is already stated, and has not been changed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use ところ: AさんがXをやる/やっているところが見たい.