# What does "というのも" mean in this context?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence "常に家の中を綺麗に掃除しておくというのも、いい女になるためにやりたいことのひとつです。" what is というのも adding? I was taught that というのも means "because" but that doesn't seem to fit here. "Always keeping the inside of your house clean is one thing you want to do to become a good woman." is my interpretation of this sentence, but how does the というのも fit in? Is it simply there to connect the clauses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a conjunctive, it is rather

- という quotative
- の nominalizer (see e.g., [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29926/45489))
- も *also*

So 常に家の中を綺麗に掃除しておくというのも is equivalent to ...ということも, which translates to *That one always keeps the house/room clean is also (one of the things you want to do to be a nice woman)*.